# DataSet и SQL-запросы

Tags: c#, sql

Если какие-то средства, которые позволяют писать запрос(Например, всякие JOIN'ы) к ADO.NET DataSet и получить в результате какую-нибудь вьюху?

Я знаю, что это проделать и руками через LINQ, но меня интересует парсер обычного SQL-запроса, который проделает все это автоматом.

Comment: делаете View, а потом вызываем через ADO.NET

Comment: Но View - это на стороне какого-нибудь SQL-сервера. А вопрос в том, что можно ли получить сырой DataSet и дать пользователю писать запросы к нему.

Comment: в LINQ to SQL есть конструктор запросов

Comment: Все кастомные запросы надо делать в DataAdapter соответ.таблицы.

Comment: Нет, sql-запросов к DataSet нету. Можно только условия фильтрации задавать. / Как вариант, почему бы не использовать sqlite in memory? Загружаем данные из взрослой БД в локальную sqlite (именно в оперативку), а к ней уже можно дать пользователю писать запросы.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov интересно. И шустро вообще работает? Если мне потребуется все это назад пульнуть в большу БД, то по идее проблем не будет?

Comment: У sqlite две проблемы: он однопользовательский (но в данном случае это не имеет никакого значения) и у него медленный update (но если делать много апдейтов в одной транзакции, то очень быстрый - порвёт всех) - опять же, в данном конкретном случае это не проблема. Конечно, придётся поломать голову из-за разных типов данных и т. п. Всё решаемо, но... овчинка стоит выделки, если только действительно позарез нужно дать юзеру писать запросы к локальному кешу данных.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, напишите в качестве ответа. Я думаю, что как альтернатива подойдет за полезный ответ. И с минимальным кодом с примером.